# Jquery not working from local disk

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Description
Jquery is not working from local disk -using a downloaded copy of any jquery version does not work ok.
it works ok from ref links over the internet.

per jquery documentation - it is suppose to work from local disk as well
(i.e script src = "local path"...).
my code works fine with reference external links to jquery lib (versions 2.2.4 , 3.2.1 ) no problem

whenever i try to fallback or just use the local downloaded file for the same version it fails!

the relevant code is

```
<script src async = './jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>  
or just
<script src = './jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
```

and i tried several other workarrounds including pasting the whole file into my html as script) none worked neither on chrome nor firefox windows 7-8 node-8.9.1
tried similar to the following as well:

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

error message is:

```
detailed error: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
detailed error: TypeError: pageExecute is undefined
```

one suggested solution is:  use dev server.
what is dev server and why  needed? means what? so i can not just use the local copy of jquery lib?

Comment: You cannot have spaces around = in HTML tags. The last example misses ./ from the beginning of path.

Comment: @ver try your js url is accessible from browser address bar

Comment: Would this work? `<script src = 'jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>` (removed the `./`)

Comment: What is the URL of your web page in the browser and where exactly on your hard drive (full path) is the jQuery file.  You are likely just not constructing the `<script>` tag properly.  We need to know both of those to know what to suggest.  Unless the web page is also being loaded from the file system, you cannot access the file system for other resources (security concern).  If the web page is being loaded from the file system, then we need to know it's exact path so we can suggest the proper relative file system URL for the jquery file.

Comment: my url is "localhost:6060" or "localhost:6060/example1" is accessible no problem .   I will try to take out any space from the local link path, and see if it is the problem. let you know tomm.

Answer (score 1):

node.js does not serve ANY files by default (unlike some other web servers).  So, if you want the jQuery file to be served by your own web server, then you need to create a route that serves that file or use something like `express.static()` that serves multiple files.

Since your web URL is `http://localhost:6060/example1`, you are loading the web page through your own web server.  Therefore any script tag such as:

```
<script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

will be requested form your own web server as:

```
http://localhost:6060/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
```

If you don't have a route defined for that specific URL in your node.js server, then you will get an error.  If you are using Express in your node.js server, then you either need something like:

```
app.use(express.static("/someDirPath"));
```

to create a middleware handler that will automatically look in `/someDirPath` for files that are requested.  Or, you need to make specific routes for files you want to serve:

```
app.get("/jquery-2.2.4.min.js", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("/somePath/jquery-2.2.4.min.js");
});
```

---

In my design projects, I make a URL distinction between static files and dynamic routes.  I use `/public` at the beginning of the URL path for any public resource as this makes it simple to distinguish which request is for a static resource and which is for a dynamically served route.  So, in my script file, I'd use:

```
<script src="/public/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

And, then on my server, I'd use:

```
// serve static resources from the public directory below our project
app.use(express.static("/public", path.join(__dirname, public)));
```

And, then I'd have a directory structure of public static files:

```
myAppDir
   various server files
   - public
        - js
        - css
        - img
```

Comment: whoever marked this question -1 should  think twice before playing games of  "big judge" . this is ridiculous.

Comment: @canadian_nerd - On a separate note, did my answer clear anything up for you?  That was over a month ago and you never commented at all on the answer so the conversation just ended.

Comment: yes is very helpfull and make sense.         i am still testing it among other bugs and challenges

Answer (score 0):

Issue with file path
If both js and html file in same folder then use:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>`